# excel INDEX not returning expected value

Tags: algorithm, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have two columns

best understood by this picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyoJ7.png

with these algorithms
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1tJH.png

so columns

```
Red 6.166666667
Blue    5.666666667
White   6.833333333
Green   5.166666667
Black   5.166666667
Yellow  6.666666667
Grn/Wht7    6
Ylw/Blk8    3.75
```

algorithms

```
=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(SMALL(K:K,1),K:K,0))   =SMALL(K:K,1)
=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(SMALL(K:K,2),K:K,0))   =SMALL(K:K,2)
=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(SMALL(K:K,3),K:K,0))   =SMALL(K:K,3)
=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(SMALL(K:K,4),K:K,0))   =SMALL(K:K,4)
=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(SMALL(K:K,5),K:K,0))   =SMALL(K:K,5)
=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(SMALL(K:K,6),K:K,0))   =SMALL(K:K,6)
=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(SMALL(K:K,7),K:K,0))   =SMALL(K:K,7)
=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(SMALL(K:K,8),K:K,0))   =SMALL(K:K,8)
```

Why is the third one, returning Green?

How do I get it to return Black?

Comment: Black and green have the same value. It always returns green because its the first match.

Comment: but i give it a different index - i say return the 4th lowest number not the first time it finds this value - how do i write the algorithm to give me the result I want?

Comment: The 4th lowest number also happens to be the 3th, because there are 2 of the same. So basically `SMALL(K:K,3)` and `SMALL(K:K,4)` is returning exactly the same thing.

Comment: J is color K is number

Comment: @Havenard I get that - what I am asking is how do I fix the algorithm so I can return my expected results?

Comment: I'm not sure. The idea of matching values to their colors is working, you only happen to have two different colors representing the same number and expect it to decide which one should be used. Perhaps you need a 3rd column to mark which colors were already taken and prevent them from being used again, but I'm not sure how you will exclude taken colors from the range.

Comment: You could add a small qualifier to differentiate between rows, though this will necessitate using fixed range references, not whole columns, e.g. (I've also used ROWS($1:1) for k and fixed the references, so that it can be copied down to give successive results for k=2, 3, etc.): =INDEX($J$1:$J$8,MATCH(SMALL(INDEX($K$1:$K$8+ROW($K$1:$K$8)/10^9,,),ROWS($1:1)),INDEX($K$1:$K$8+ROW($K$1:$K$8)/10^9,,),0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the colours in J2:J9 and the associated numbers in K2:K9 and you want results in P2:Q9

Put this formula in `P2`

`=SMALL(K$2:K$9,ROWS(P$2:P2))`

and this one in `Q2`

`=INDEX(J$2:J$9,SMALL(IF(K$2:K$9=P2,ROW(K$2:K$9)-ROW(K$2)+1),COUNTIF(P$2:P2,P2)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

copy both down to row 9

In the second formula the `COUNTIF` part ensures that you get different colours returned for matching numbers because it counts the instances down to that point, incrementing each row when there are ties

see screenshot

[image]